# Change the background of an item in a ListView displayed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` populated from a database using a customized `ResourceCursorAdapter` with a `bindView` to format each list item.  The items are displayed in descending chronological order and I need to hightlight the first future event.  Unfortunately I only know that it is the first future event when I process the next entry and find that it is in the past.  What I really need is the ability to 'look ahead' in the bindView processing but that is not there.

The only alternative (that I can think of) is to process all items and then go back to change the background of the first future event (which I would then know).

The code I'm using is

```
    EventsAdapter db = new EventsAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    Cursor cursor = db.fetchAllRecords();

    final MyAdapter listitems = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.timeline_detail, cursor, 0);
    timeline.setAdapter(listitems);

    db.close();

    View v = timeline.getChildAt(firstEvent);  // firstevent is set in the bindView
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd1d1"));
```

However the View v is always null and, when I run it in debug mode with a breakpoint at the View statement, the listview has not yet rendered on the screen.  I'm assuming, therefore, that that is why the view is still null.

How can I get and `changeView` the `ListView` item that needs to be changed at the time that the `ListView` is first displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and extend your adapter and override getView.

```
final MyAdapter listitems = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.timeline_detail, cursor, 0){
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position==0){
            //Do something to the first item (v)
        }else{
            //Revert what you did above, since views get recycled.
        }
        return v;
    }
};
```

or just include that in your MyAdapter class.

Comment: Thanks, but this is only partially working.  I have a cursor with 14 records in it of which 8 are displayed on screen at any one time.  When I first run the app the correct record is being highlighted (which is what I'm doing in the getView) but as I scroll up and down the highlighted item keeps changing with sometimes up to 4 items being highlighted.

Comment: So the highlighted view gets recycled? This is what I'm understanding. In this case you just need to put an `else {}` to that `if` and set the normal background that you want for the rest of the items there.

Comment: Many thanks.  Adding the else fixed the problem. Just for my enlightenment, can you explain the relationship between bindview and getview. Does bindview call getview for each row passing in the cursor position as the position?

Comment: It's the other way around. `CursorAdapter` has an implementation of `getView` that calls `newView` and `bindView`. Normally you don't need to override `getView` because it is replaced by the other 2 methods, but your case is a bit different and you need to know the `position`.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation - it has increased my knowledge of android sdk that bit further - thanks

Comment: I edited the answer so future wanderers don't have to read the comments for the `else` part. Good luck learning Android, dude.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86621/discussion-between-andrei-tudor-diaconu-and-doug-conran).